# SelectedIndexChanged not firing when dropdownlist selection made

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a test gridview where I'm attempting to place a numerical value into a textbox when the spelled out number is selected as a dropdown selection.  The first row works fine but when it comes to rows 2 & 3 the event doesn't fire at all when any of the selections from the dropdownmenu are selected.

The code is pretty straight forward and I'm stumped as to what's going on here.  I'm pretty sure It's something simple but at this point I'm just spinning my proverbial wheels.

Here's the ASP code (non essential code stripped out)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="Customer ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="Customer Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number Value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList Width="50" runat="server" ID="ddlTest" AutoPostBack="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server">

        </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>

   </asp:GridView>
```

And here's the code behind....

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Web2008
{

    public partial class GridViewDropDown : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                List<Customer> lst = new List<Customer>();
                Customer cust1 = new Customer();
                cust1.CustomerID = 1;
                cust1.CustomerName = "Customer1";
                Customer cust2 = new Customer();
                cust2.CustomerID = 2;
                cust2.CustomerName = "Customer2";
                Customer cust3 = new Customer();
                cust3.CustomerID = 3;
                cust3.CustomerName = "Customer3";

                lst.Add(cust1);
                lst.Add(cust2);
                lst.Add(cust3);
                GridView1.DataSource = lst;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {

                Control ctrl = row.FindControl("ddlTest") as DropDownList;
                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)ctrl;

                    if (ddl.ClientID == ddl.ClientID)
                    {
                        TextBox txt = row.FindControl("txtTest") as TextBox;
                        txt.Text = ddl1.SelectedValue;
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.CommandName);
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                Control ctrl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlTest");
                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                    DropDownList dd = ctrl as DropDownList;

                    List<DropDownData> lst = new List<DropDownData>();
                    DropDownData cust1 = new DropDownData(1, "One");
                    DropDownData cust2 = new DropDownData(2, "Two");
                    DropDownData cust3 = new DropDownData(3, "Thres");

                    lst.Add(cust1);
                    lst.Add(cust2);
                    lst.Add(cust3);

                    dd.DataTextField = "Text";
                    dd.DataValueField = "ID";
                    dd.DataSource = lst;
                    dd.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

        public class DropDownData
        {
            public DropDownData(int id, string displaytext)
            {
                iD = id;
                Text = displaytext;
            }
            int iD;
            public int ID
            {
                get { return iD; }
                set { iD = value; }
            }
            string text;
            public string Text
            {
                get { return text; }
                set { text = value; }
            }
        }

    public class Customer
        {
        public int CustomerID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        }

        public string CustomerName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the selected index event handler have you tried this?

```
if (ddl.ClientID == ddl1.ClientID)
```

Your if clause is comparing two values that are the same

Comment: (bangs head repeatedly)  That was it.  ::sigh::  Thanks @diogod!